# SimpleXML not working with Yahoo Answers

Tags: php, simplexml, yahoo

```
$bot = file_get_contents("http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch?appid=API_KEY&query=".$q1."");
echo $bot->Question[0]->ChosenAnswer;
```

For some reason, the script isn't returning anything.

Comment: You are not using SimpleXML anywhere in that code.  `file_get_contents` returns you a string.

Comment: P.S. Don't add your API keys to the question.  You should probably change it.

Comment: I've asked many questions, but this is probably my stupidest. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: *"For some reason"* - when asking a question, please share what the reason according to your understanding is and why you're not able to solve it your own. That creates more value with the question, otherwise it's just a dumping of code and "not working! help! heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelp!!!!" which is just for the trashcan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to create instance of SimpleXML to use it.

```
$bot = file_get_contents("http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch?appid=API_KEY&query=".$q1."");
$bot = simplexml_load_string($bot);
echo $bot->Question[0]->ChosenAnswer;
```

Comment: I've asked many questions, but this is probably my stupidest. Anyways, thanks for your help. Sometimes the simple things take a while to figure out for me :\